# Strange Unterminated String literal error

Tags: python, django, syntax

I'm making a simple todo app with Django but the error *Unterminated String literal* is creating a lot of problems. I know there is no unterminated string literal but the error keeps arriving? What might be the cause? The line with div role=button is creating the problem.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content%}
{% if object_list %}
<h3>All my lists</h3>
{% endif %}

<ul>
    {% for todolist in object_list%}
    <li>
       <div role="button" onclick="location.href='{% url "list" todolist.id %}'">
        {{ todolist.title}}
       </div>
    </li>
    {% empty %}
    <h4>You have no list</h4>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Pleae edit your question and add the relevant code as text, not as an image.

Comment: The quotes match up to the first set of matching ones. You probably need to escape those in the middle.

Comment: Just edited the question to remove image and input code

Comment: Still the same problem!!